# How to handle different path parameters for different environments using pactjs

Tags: javascript, pact

I have started to implement PACT for CDC testing. How can I handle the scenario where we pass different parameters in the path for different environments?

For example my test calls a function which requests some data from a service by hitting the endpoint and passing some parameters. Very standard.

E.G:  `api/nodeId/${nodeId}/userId/${userId}`

For different environments (QA, UAT etc) unique data specific to that environment must be passed in order to elicit a valid 200 response. So in my example carId and userId will need to be different for each env. When I set my test up originally I used our QA environment and got the following contract generated.

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "myConsumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "myProvider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request to view nodes",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/api/nodeId/RRTT6-3AFA-4B5B-BF76-5B6AC7/userId/123456789",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "startTime": 1549652248000,
          "endTime": 1549911448000,
          "startPrice": 83576,
          "reservePrice": 83876,
          "price": 84576,
          "status": null,
          "groupList": [
            "78945"
          ],
          "bids": 0,
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the path in the contract has a nodeId and userId hardcoded. If I tried to validate against a different environment these tests would fail. So how can I re-use the same contract for different environments? Currently for different environments I am generating a separate contract for each, but seems like there must be another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `term` [Matcher](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js#match-by-regular-expression) for dynamic paths, but as Fabrico warns, having specific pieces of data per environment is a dangerous game to be playing. It is common for the provider to have different IDs for all kinds of reasons, so where possible try to decouple your tests from being dependent on these.

e.g. with path matchers:

```
const { Pact, Matchers } = require('@pact-foundation/pact');
const { term } = Matchers;

provider.addInteraction({
  state: 'has node ID 1234 and user with ID 5678',
  uponReceiving: 'a request to view nodes',
  withRequest: {
    method: 'GET',
    api/nodeId/${nodeId}/userId/${userId}
    path: term({ generate: '/api/nodeId/RRTT6-3AFA-4B5B-BF76-5B6AC7/userId/123456789', matcher: '/api/nodeId/[A-Z0-9\-]+/userId/[0-9]+' })
  },
  willRespondWith: {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: { ... }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It’s usually not a good idea to rely on external environment variables to run your tests, mainly because one of the advantages of using Client Driven Contracts is that your producers can be tested in isolation, even isolation from the environment. That means that your tests should set up the things it relies on or be flexible and not depend on specific environment configuration. This is what you should do for any automated test, not only CDC.

In your scenario you could, for instance, create the user specified in the contract before your test starts or mock your user adapter to return a valid user no matter the user id passed. The answer here will depend on how your consumer uses the `nodeId` and `userId`.

Comment: Hi Fabricio. - Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

The provider verification is generally run against a locally running provider on your local machine or your continuous integration build node. It's not intended to be run against a deployed environment, and it somewhat defeats the purpose to use it like that. The advantage of contract testing is that you should know *before* you deploy whether or not the services will work together. Join us on [slack.pact.io](https://slack.pact.io) and have a talk to us if you're confused about this.

Comment: Hi Beth. No that makes sense all right. I originally thought it would be easier to get it setup and running if we used an existing test env with data, but I can see now that that introduces it's own complexity. Thanks for your feedback!